# How to update only the non-existing documents and delete the old documents which doesnot exist now using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb

I am using `mongoimport` in order to import a bunch of JSONs and I am looking for a way 
to

1. only to import records that don't exist
2. keep the matching records
3. delete the old records (which are not in the newly inserted jsons)

Comment: You'll need to write some code to do that manually (via your favorite programming language) as it exceeds the capabilities of mongoimport.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to keep only collection in your export right ? If so, take a look at the following options:

> --drop Modifies the restoration procedure to drop every collection from the target database before restoring the collection from the
>   dumped backup.
>
> --upsert Modifies the import process to update existing objects in the database if they match an imported object, while inserting all other
>   objects.
>
> If you do not specify a field or fields using the --upsertFields
>   mongoimport will upsert on the basis of the _id field.

More information on [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/)

Comment: I have tried these options ; but i dont want to drop all the existing dcoumnts, upsert with fileds will update the matching document ; I wish to only drop the data which is not in the new data set. the problem here is that i have some docs in the database collection and i get the updated data from a source(which contains old, new plus updated data) and now need to update the same in the collection. How can i do that using mongoimport (without using drop)

Comment: Well, if your data from source is the most recent (containing new, updated and removed data) then why can't you replace it using `drop` ?